# How to detect exact offset top() using jquery after scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table i want to detect offset top of `TR` where is clicked this is working fine but after scroll page this is not working fine. Why after scroll offset().top is changed? How can fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
    console.log(offsetTop);
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myDiv">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 1</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 2</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 3</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 4</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 5</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 6</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 7</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 8</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 9</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July 10</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need `position()` instead of `offset()`.

Comment: I have to detect offset from top not position @artanik

Comment: Your code is working as expected; after scrolling the `offset().top` of the clicked `tr` is relevant to the top of the visible area. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan actually my code is working as expected but after scrolling its not working fine as earlier, suppose you first click on second TR and scroll page then click on same TR then this will give offset() top different. how can i do it same?

Comment: That's my point - that is the expected behaviour as the `offset()` is relevant to the position of the page content compared to the visible extents of the browser. Without knowing what you're trying to do we can't help you. Why would you need to have the same pixel value when clicking on the `tr` at different scroll positions? There's better ways to match elements instead of comparing relevant positions on screen

Comment: Thanks @artanik for suggest me, i need to use position() instead of offset().

Answer (score 0):

You could always calculate the offset, factoring in the scroll position:

```
var offset_t = $(selector).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
var offset_l = $(selector).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
```